# Android Studio : How to copy a text from TextView or EditText in a single Line

Tags: android, android-studio, copy-paste

I am making an application that encrypt a text and copy it automaticly.

Here is the XML :

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Text To Encrypt or To Decrypt"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtkey"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter KEY"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtsalt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter SALT"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtres"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Result"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnencrypt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Encrypt" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btndecrypt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Decrypt" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnclear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Clear" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the Btnencrypt code which it does encryption + copy to the encrypted text

```
        btnencrypt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String encrypted = Encrypt(txt.getText().toString(), txtkey.getText().toString(),txtsalt.getText().toString());
            txtres.setText(encrypted);
            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", txtres.getText().toString().trim());
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Encrypted Text Copied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            txt.setText("");
        }
    });
```

when I past the encrypted text into Notepad++ , it takes a weird format : 2 lines of text and one empty line. What I want is to past the whole text in a single line , see the image bellow

http://hpics.li/e355430

**EDIT:**

**By Adding .trim() , The useless line is deleted but Im still having 2 lines of text instead of a single line**

```
btnencrypt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String encrypted = Encrypt(txt.getText().toString().trim(), txtkey.getText().toString().trim(),txtsalt.getText().toString().trim());
        txtres.setText(encrypted.trim());
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", txtres.getText().toString());
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Encrypted Text Copied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        txt.setText("");
    }
});
```

Comment: add at first  `toString().trim()`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya By Adding .trim() , The useless line is deleted but Im still having 2 lines of text instead of a single line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not simply strip out the formatting?

```
ClipData.newPlainText("label", textView.getText().toString().replaceAll("\n", "").trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `trim()` while you try to gettext from object like...

```
 txtres.setText(Decrypt(txt.getText().toString().trim(), txtkey.getText().toString().trim(),txtsalt.getText().toString().trim()));
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", txtres.getText().toString().trim());
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```

Comment: good , the last line is now deleted , but Im still having 2 lines of text instead of 1 line

Answer (score 0):

add following parameters to `textView` check below code

```
    String encrypted = Encrypt(txt.getText().toString(), txtkey.getText().toString(),txtsalt.getText().toString());
    txtres.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    txtres.setSingleLine(true);
    txtres.setMaxLines(1);
    txtres.setLines(1);
    txtres.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1); // marquee forever
    txtres.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
    txtres.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
    txtres.setFocusable(true);
    txtres.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    txtres.setSelected(true);
    txtres.setLayoutParams(params);
    txtres.setTextSize(30);
    txtres.setText(encrypted.trim());
    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", txtres.getText().toString());
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Encrypted Text Copied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    txt.setText("");
```